# how to add DropDownComobo in uisearchbar ios

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar

I want to add one dropdowncombo in UISearchBar like mail application (NSTokenField).

On clicking that combo it will display the list of items. I have read many blogs but there is no public control from Apple. Is there way to do this?

Comment: In apple, there is no way to create dropdown using their package. You can use thirt party library.

Comment: You can use picker or have to made it in the custom way by taking the view and the table view on it.

Answer (score 1):

NO. you have to use UIPickerview or UISegmentedControl to create a drop down menu.

If you want custom control,you can check this link:-

https://github.com/katokichisoft/KSPopoverView

if you need any further assistance..please reply to me..

you can also use action sheet..Its upto you..

enjoy..

Comment: you can also check this link:- http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/iphone-development/custom-dropdown-list/

Comment: I have seen both the code. I think I have to write own code for this. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @NiteshMeshram   You are welcome and you search cocoa control and code app.com ..you may get exactly what you need..

Answer (score 0):

There is no build in control to make dropdowncombo. Instead you can use picker or as in mail application there is a custom controller. you can make it Simply by a table view on a view and presenting it. You can also show the list of Items in the UIPopOverController by adding the controller having table view and manage the content size of the popover.